# Python requests are installed, but when trying to upload JSON via Python it says no such module exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using a Python upload file to connect an Apple News Format JSON file to my publisher. I've installed Python 3.6.1 and (I believe) 2.7 via Homebrew, and have used the following command to install requests:

```
$ pip3 install requests
```

This successfully installed the requests package. When dragging my "upload.py" file into Terminal, followed by "article.json", I receive the following error:

```
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Here is a screenshot to corroborate that these requests are, in fact, installed:

[image]

I have no idea what the problem is. Considering that I'm just doing this to change my article formatting, this is one hell of a job. I even downloaded the requests zip file to be certain. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  It sounds like you might be running Python 2.7, but the requests module is only installed for Python 3.6.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure which is the running version at the moment (I'm a front-end guy messing with forces that I don't understand haha). Using a pip command in Terminal doesn't work, but a pip3 command does. So I'm assuming Python 3. As for the upload.py file that was supplied to me, I'm not sure which syntax that follows

Comment: How do you run the code?  By typing `python upload.py` in your terminal window?  If so, run `python --version` and it will tell you.

Comment: @John Gordon the Python version it gave me is 2.7.10. To run it, I drag the upload.py file from Finder into Terminal, followed by the JSON file it's meant to upload

Comment: Well that explains it.  `requests` is installed for Python 3, but you're using Python 2 to run your code.  Is there a reason you used `pip3` to install requests, instead of plain `pip`?

Comment: I actually ended up using `pip3` because the `pip install requests` command was not working. Terminal actually says `pip: command not found`. I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Another option would be to use Python 3 to run your code, as in `python3 upload.py`, although this would require that the program was written to be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Run with python3. `python3 upload.py`

Comment: Would `python3 upload.py` be the command I'd put into Terminal to do so?

Comment: Yes, that's the right command.

Comment: Terminal throws me this error when doing so: `print response.status_code
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`. My print calls are currently structured as so in my `upload.py` file: `print response.status_code print response.text` on two separate lines. Where would the parentheses be added to make the syntax comply?

Comment: The correct syntax for Python 3 is `print (response.text)`.  However: the change from `print` being a keyword in Python 2 to being a function call in Python 3 is a very superficial difference between the two versions; there are other differences that are not so easily fixed. I am pessimistic that this change by itself will make your code compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Hey all, I ended up downloading python2 as well, for testing purposes, and the `pip install requests` command was successful in installing requests for Python 2.7.13. After changing the syntax back to satisfy Python 2, I still received the message `ImportError: module named requests not found`. In short, what the hell?